# say something in parentheses

Tags: journal-publishing, journal

So the question is simple: What is the common way of saying something in parentheses in a journal paper like engineering or mathematics.

Assume you are talking about a mathematical approach, but in the middle you want to point out to something else, or mention an special case. I give an example:

"...our approach is based on the following linear equations....

Eq.(1).....

(now here I want to make a big parenthesis or a break to discuss about something regarding the approach which is not too long to be considered as an Appendix, maybe only one paragraph )

One can think of the other approach such as .....[a symbol to indicate the end of Remark]"

So the question is it, how this feature is normally handled in papers, and what is the latex function to do so.

It seems that a "Remark" environment is the suitable one for this case, but what symbol should be used to terminate/close the Remark?  can I use an "end of proof" mark such as a solid black suare?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure i am getting you, you want to put there a few sentences (or a paragraph) that are somehow different and the reader should see that? How about just using a sans-serif font? Or Italics?

Comment: I think this is more a question of semantics than of LaTeX? I think this is appropriate either for the English site, or the Academia site. Once you know what is _correct_, then come ask specifically about such usages. :)

Comment: I want to do some calculations and show another approach which are not used in our paper and thus the reader can simply skip that if he is not interested, or in other words, if he skips that piece, nothing will happen because the rest of the paper never uses that piece of calculations. you can think of it as a footnote functionality, but it is in the main column and not in the footer.

Comment: You should definitely go ask http://english.stackexchange.com/ or http://academia.stackexchange.com/ (But to me, a "big footnote" as what you are trying to do simply go in the annex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remark-like material is sufficiently important to belong in the body of the document (as opposed to being consigned to a footnote or endnote), you could create a dedicated remark-like environment for it to offset it visually from the surrounding the material.

The following suggested solution employs the `ntheorem` package to create an environment called `spremark` (short for "special remark").

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain} % no need to number these remarks, right? 
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}   % use ordinary (upright) font shape
\newtheorem{spremark}{Remark} % "special remark"

\begin{document}
\dots

\begin{spremark} 
Now here I want to make a big parenthesis or a break to discuss something regarding the approach which is not too long to be considered as an Appendix, maybe only one paragraph. \end{spremark}

\dots
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum: If you want to mark the end of the `spremark` environment with a symbol such as `\diamond`, use the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamond}}
\newtheorem{spremark}{Remark} % "special remark"
```

The only symbols I would *not* use for this purpose are open and solid squares, since those may well be mistaken for end-of-proof markers. No need to confuse your readers by using the same symbol for the ends of proof and remark environments, right?

Comment: That would be one good suggestion, do we need to put separator or line ruler or something before and after this remark box? or maybe special symbol at the end of the sentence in the remark? something like a square as some put at the end of a proof!

Comment: @ehsank - The answers to your questions depend crucially on just how prominent, visually speaking, *you* want the remark(s) to be.

Comment: I mean at least end of Remark should be somehow visible.

Comment: @ehsank - it would have been useful if had mentioned these criteria up front, i.e., in your initial query.

Comment: @ehsank - I've provided an addendum to show how to automatically add a symbol at the end of the remark environment.